# OpenVino for Intel HD Graphic

Tags: intel, openvino

I have processor Intel® Core™ i7-7700 Processor. I am trying to run [OpenVino](https://software.intel.com/en-us/openvino-toolkit) on Intel GPU.

According to specs [here](https://ark.intel.com/products/series/95544/7th-Generation-Intel-Core-i7-Processors), the CPU has Intel® HD Graphics 630 built in.

So that means, I have Intel GPU inside and just need to have right driver for GPU according to discussion [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/OpenVINO-Install-Windows#Install%20GPU).

I just want to make sure I don't need external GPU like Nvidia if I want to use Intel HD Graphics.

Answer (score 1):

That's right, GPU support in OpenVino means Intel GEN or Intel HD Graphics. You don't need external GPU to try OV.